# Error with tuple

Tags: python

I am recieving an attribute error code -´which states that my tuple object has no attribute "size".

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'

This is my code: https://pastebin.com/uCE5Uy1M

and this is the part of where I recieve the error:

```
for x in range(0, 640, tile.size):
            for y in range(0, 480, tile.size):
                for i in map_data:
                    tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)
                    if (x, y) == tile:
                        window.blit(tile.textures_tags[i[2]], (x + globals.camera_x, y + globals.camera_y))
```

I am new to python and do not understand my error, since i did define "size" on my sec. python file, which I placed in the same folder. It worked perfectly fine before I added this part.

Here is the link to my sec file called textures.py : https://pastebin.com/z1uMPBjd

Could someone please explain this issue for me?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and venture that `tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)` (which is creating a 2-element tuple), should be constructing a new `tile` object instead.

Comment: by constructing you mean defining my tile just like in my texttures.py?

Comment: Since the error notifies that `tile` is a `tuple`, use `len(tile)` instead of `tile.size`.

Comment: I just replaced tile.size with len(tile)... now it says "TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@all!

I recieved some help from my professor and the solution is replacing;

```
tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)
```

with

```
this_tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)
```

and everything is working perfectly now.

This was his explanation:

> In the tuple you've just created, there are no named fields. Hence,
>   the interpreter does not find `size` anymore. If you change the line
>   to `this_tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)` and then use in
>   the subsequent lines `this_tile` instead of `tile` it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning your `tile` object in this line into a `tuple` instead:

```
tile = (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size)
```

You might want to just drop this line altogether and just compare the results with `(x, y)` since you seem to still want to use the `tile` object and had no need to retain the calculated result further than the comparison:

```
for x in range(0, 640, tile.size):
    for y in range(0, 480, tile.size):
        for i in map_data:
            if (x, y) == (i[0] * tile.size, i[1] * tile.size):
                window.blit(tile.textures_tags[i[2]], (x + globals.camera_x, y + globals.camera_y))
```

If you needed the result for other purposes, assign it to some other name instead of `tile` (e.g. `tile_position`).